# Search in php from dat file

Tags: php, search

I'm trying to Search my orderid, This is my code so far:

```
<?php
$file = 'order.dat';
$searchfor = '177';

// the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

// get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
// escape special characters in the query
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
// finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
// search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "Found matches:\n";
   echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
}
else{
   echo "No matches found";
}
```

now for example my `order.dat` file contains the data

```
175|RC456456456|54156456465|109$

176|RC456456456|54156456465|177$

177|RC456456456|54156456465|129$

178|RC456456456|54156456465|129$
```

now when i searchfor 177 i have an result like this:-

```
Found matches:
176|RC456456456|54156456465|177$
177|RC456456456|54156456465|129$
```

But i want to search 177 for my 1st string only

I want my result like this, its only match my 1st string not on all 4 variables

```
177|RC456456456|54156456465|129$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to match only those string ***that begin with*** `177`. If yes you can change your regex to:

```
$pattern = "/^$pattern.*$/m";
```

Comment: :) I want my result like this,177|RC456456456|54156456465|129$

Comment: :) one more question is it possible to make a function of this script?

Comment: @david: What exactly do you want the function to do?

Comment: :) if i want to search it from date what i can do can u plz help me ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = "/^$pattern/m"; // your string starts (^) with $pattern (177) 
                           // and we dont care what it ends with
```

Answer (score 0):

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/3fff8.php

```
$pattern = "/^$pattern.*?\$/m";
```

instead of

```
$pattern = "/^.*|$pattern.*\$/m";
```

Comment: :) i want this result 177|RC456456456|54156456465|129$

Comment: :) if i want to search it from date what i can do can u plz help me ?